# Seeing Duplicate Collections

Tags: google-docs-api

I have a .Net application written using Version 3 of the Google Docs API. Haven't had time to look at updating to the Drive API.

Within the past few days I've gotten a report from one client that they sometimes get a new collection or sub-collection created when my application uploads a new document. I have code which uses "https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/folder%3Aroot/contents/-/folder" to find the list of root collections and it then drills down from there as needed to find the proper place to insert the new item using the ID for the collection or sub-collection. For example: Level One\Level Two\Level Three-->new item.

The program usually finds Level One when it looks for it but then will suddenly create a new Level One and add everything under that (it will create sub-levels as needed). Just as suddenly it will go back to using the original Level One (I can see that they have two items named the same but with different IDs) and new items will appear there. They've set permissions to share the original collection but the duplicate collection doesn't get those permissions and that causes a real problem.

Is this some sort of timing or availability problem?

Thanks!